# How to replace organization email id on the existing azure account

Tags: azure, email, azure-active-directory, office365

We have an Azure account all users/developers access the Azure resources by the organization email id for example `emailid@abc.com`.
As the organization has grown it has split the business into 2 different organizations now and all the users/developers email id is changed to `emailid@xyz.com`.

What is the recommended solution to seamlessly replace `emailid@abc.com` to `emailid@xyz.com` so that users/developers can access azure resources with no issues. The users / Developer has also subscribed there email id for job success and failure alerts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@abc.com` is the primary domain in your Azure tenant. You can add your new custom domain name (`@xyz.com`) [using the Azure Active Directory portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/add-custom-domain) or [O365 admin center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/setup/add-domain?view=o365-worldwide).

Then set `@xyz.com` as the primary domain for all users. In this way, users can directly use the account with the new domain name to access Azure resources.

Comment: Thanks this is helpful , need one more help on how do we manage access for Azure Databricks.

Comment: @nilesh1212  As I mentioned, after you use the new domain account, you can still access the Azure resources which you have access to previously. So what is the issue you are facing with accessing Azure Databricks currently? Please provide more details.

Comment: Azure Databricks has all together a different Admin page for access and permission where we list all users with email ids hence wanted to check how it will be impacted at azure databricks level. Do we need to manually change each email id with new email id at Databricks level?

Comment: @nilesh1212 I'm not familiar with Azure Databricks. But in fact, the `emailid@xyz.com` is still `emailid@abc.com`. They are the same account. Just changed a domain name. Therefore, for the same account, the resources that were previously accessible should still be accessible now.

Comment: @nilesh1212 `@abc.com` is your Azure domain? What about `@xyz.com`?

Comment: @nilesh1212 This statement of “Azure account” is not accurate and can cause ambiguity. An Azure tenant should only contain one organization. So I understand that `@abc.com` is your Azure domain name. But where does `@xyz.com come` from? Is it another Azure tenant or just a third-party domain name?

Comment: Sorry my limited knowledge on Azure... I meant the email id we use for login into Azure portal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232847/discussion-between-allen-wu-and-nilesh1212).